# $ z_1^k+\cdots +z_n^k=0$ for all $k$ implies $z_i=0$ for all $i$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

Suppose $z_1,...,z_n\in \Bbb C$ are complex numbers, not necessarily distinct, satisfying $$ z_1^k+\cdots +z_n^k=0$$

$ \color{red}{\forall\; k>0}$. Then is it true that $z_1=\cdots=z_n=0$?

This will be obvious if the $z_i$'s  were all real, but I'm wondering that this is true for the complex case.

Comment: Yes it is true. Do you know how to covert those equations into showing that $\sum \prod_{i \text{terms} } x_ax_b \ldots  = 0$ ? Hence, by vieta, $z_i$ are the roots of $z^n = 0$, so $z_i = 0$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/811913/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1203786/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2963882/42969.

Comment: @MartinR I doubt that the first link is related to this question. Well, maybe they are vaguely related via Newton's formulae.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another point of view, with recursion and linear algebra. Consider the following assumption hypothesis $H(n)$.

*For all $z_1, \dots, z_n \in \mathbb{C}$, if for some $a_1, \dots, a_n > 0$, and all $k \in \{1, \dots, n\}$, we have
$$
a_1 z_1^k + \cdots + a_n z_n^k,
$$
then $z_1 = \cdots = z_n = 0$.*

This a generalization of the result, necessary for the induction below.

So let us show this. Clearly, $H(1)$ is true, so assume $H(n-1)$, and take $z_1, \dots, z_n$ and $a_1, \dots, a_n$ as above. If one of the $z_i$ is $0$, then we use the $H(n-1)$ and we are done. Otherwise, consider the $n \times n$ matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & z_1 & z_1^2 & \cdots & z_1^{n-1} \\
1 & z_2 & z_2^2 & \cdots & z_2^{n-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & z_n & z_n^2 & \cdots & z_n^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then if $u$ is the vector $(a_1 z_1,a_2 z_2,\dots,a_n z_n)$ (which is non-zero by assumption), you are saying that $uA = 0$. In particular, $A$ is not invertible. But this is a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), so it means that two of the $z_i$ are the same, say for instance $z_1 = z_2$. Then we can use the assumption hypothesis with $z_1, z_3, \dots, z_n$ and $a_1+a_2, a_3, \dots, a_n$ (note that $a_1+a_2 > 0$), to find that all the $z_i$ are zero.

**Note.** The assumption on the $a_i$ being strictly positive could be improved to make this more general and work in any field of characteristic $0$, for instance by saying that any sum of the $a_i$ is non-zero.

Comment: I just realized that the comments above already mention a similar solution...

Comment: Is there an argument like this for proving $x_1^k+\dots+x_n^k = y_1^k+\dots+y_n^k$ for $0 \le k \le n-1$ implies $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\} = \{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$?

Comment: This seems more delicate. Just take $n=2$. Define $A = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & x_1^2 \\ x_2 & x_2^2 \end{pmatrix}$, $B = \begin{pmatrix}  y_1 & y_1^2 \\  y_2 & y_2^2 \end{pmatrix}$, and let $u = (1,1)$. Then the assumption can be summarized as $u A = u B$. It tells that $A-B$ is not invertible, so its determinant $(x_1-y_1)(x_2-y_2)(x_2+y_2-x_1-y_1)$ is $0$. However, you cannot deduce from this that $\{x_1,y_1\} = \{x_2,y_2\}$. So you would need to get more from the assumption $uA = uB$, but I am not sure what.

Comment: lol, I asked that question because I know the exact same argument you used in your answer (which you tried to do in your comment above for $n=2$) will not work. I'm asking if there's any argument using linear algbera.

Comment: Not that I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Sure, if $k=2$ we have $z_1^2+...+z_n^2=0$ and $$(z_1+...+z_n)^2=0$$

so $$z_1z_2+...+z_{n-1}z_n=0$$

and so on... So by [Newton formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) and Vieta formulas you get that coeficients of polynomial with zeroes $z_1,z_2...$ are zero which means that all $z_i=0$.